# Broken image on mobile device

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-404, broken-links

One of my images showed a broken image link, but only on mobile devices. In all my desktop browsers, even when resizing the browser window, the image was still showing. The file path of the `<img>` tag was correct and there was no CSS or JS targeting the image, except for literally only a `width` and a `margin` CSS property. After searching for puzzle pieces for about an hour, I finally figured out what fixed the problem but not what caused it.

The image tag I used:

`<img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="image alt tag">`

What ultimately solved the problem:

`<img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="image alt tag" />`

(notice the / at the end of the tag)

Why does this little / make such a big difference? And why do all other images, with the exact same CSS class and file paths, show no problems? What does this / actually do?

Comment: in desktop the browser read it as HTML and don't need to close the <img> tag, In this case your mobile browser read it as XHTML which need to close the <img /> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding that "/" (Or "Closing Bracket") to the end of the img tag, you are validating it for XML or XHTML. HTML does not require that ending bracket (It is optional in HTML, the code will work either way), but XML/XHTML does require it.

Since your mobile browser did not show the image without the bracket, but correctly showed it with the bracket (And your PC showed it both ways), that most likely means your mobile browser is parsing the code using XML/XHTML (Where the "/" is required) and your PC is parsing it in HTML (Where the code works with, or without the "/").

Hope that helped in clarification! Comment if you don't understand something I said or would like clarification :)

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies a lot :) but what about the other images? They use the same class, same `<img>` tag but only a different file path. They were still showing on my mobile device.

Comment: That is weird, and I wouldn't know the answer to that. Perhaps it was having a caching problem with the image that needed the "/"? If it was a cache issue, then adding the "/" made it re-evaluate the tag, and that would mean that it parses in HTML (And not in XML/XHTML). It just may have been looking for a non-existent file at the time. It really is impossible to say.

Comment: This was a cache issue, you were right. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!